# Can't get a text window to appear, anyone know what to do?

Tags: visual-studio

I already tried changing the font, text colour and theme but still nothing. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and opened Visual Studio through Unity, here's the image:

[image: 1]

Comment: make sure the text window is in front of your main camera

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens to me too, double click on the script and it pops up the blank Visual Studio screen like that. To resolve the error I just go back to Unity (keeping Visual Studio open) and double click on the script, at which point the script appears on Visual Studio.